# Sitecore content editor will not load

Tags: c#, sitecore

A bad assembly or sublayout has been added to our Sitecore environment resulting in the content editor area being gray with no items to click on...

[image]

Here's what I've done..

1. Deleted all custom sublayouts with their assemblies from the date in question.
2. Cleared the website/temp folder.
3. Refreshed IIS site & did a recycle on app pool & IIS reset.

UPDATE: Most js errors seem to be uncaught reference errors..
[image]

Still cannot get the content editor to appear. No errors in log.
Please advise..

Comment: Have you checked the javascript console for errors?

Comment: I have 19 JS errors, thanks for the heads up..could these be cached somewhere? all offending files seem to be removed..

Comment: What is the error? Which version of Sitecore? MVC or ASP.Net?

Comment: Error SS above, Sitecore 6.6, ASP.NET

Comment: Can you check the Network panel and see if you have 404 or 500 errors for the js files?

Comment: Out of all my resources I've got a 'cancelled' status for msajaxwebforms and msajax. These look important. the rest of the files have an unedited status of 304 and a success of 200...No MVC and version 6.6

Comment: Just been told this issue happened when another person deployed a sublayout with .dll to Sitecore. These files have been manually deleted but weird that JS issues persist

Comment: Does a sublayout get registered in the cache somewhere to where the sitecore instance still holds it memory? Also, this deployed was simply putting a sublayout in the layouts folder and a .dll in the bin. A DB sublayout item was not even created for it yet...

Comment: How was the deployment executed?  This was probably not caused by the sublayout and custom dll.  More likely, something else was changed as part of that deployment.  Please check the Sitecore log files for errors.  Make sure that all of the Sitecore dlls are present and their versions match the expected installed versions.

Comment: it was a manual deploy, copy paste to the folders I mentioned above..I'm at the point of a rebuild now..

Comment: Just replaced the files with a working copy of Sitecore but retained the DB's and its still not working. Next step, restore working DB..

Comment: Which environment is this? Can you not just deploy as per normal, like you would a first time install? Or restore from source control or worst case from Production?

Comment: This is a dev environment. It consists of about 1000 SVN repo files and 25000 sitecore website files. All dev instances have their own DB on the farm. QA has its own DB and website as well. When we initially deploy we checkout part of the site and extract the other part until we have a working copy of sitecore locally. I just found a few minutes ago that one of our custom sublayout projects, thats configured to output to sitecore local instance upon build, sent some MSAJAX dll to the BIN and crashed content editor. Will know this for next time, what a headache for such a simple problem..:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen this before, I would check to see if you have a Microsoft AJAX dll in your bin, and if you don't need it you should get rid of it and all references to it.

Comment: That was it everyone! Thank you Thank you! Moral of the story, be aware that when you do copy activities upon building a 3rd party application, set your copy local appropriately...The 3rd party app had copy local = true for all references, and one of them was an MS AJAX .dll

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to connect a clean Sitecore installation to your database?  If you also experience the problem with the clean installation, then it is likely something that was changed at the database level that is giving you a problem.